# Can't include GTK.h in c after i install it on windows

Tags: c, installation, gtk, libraries, msys2

1- i installed  MSYS2 installer.

2- i opened the MSYS2 shell and i wrote this command

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3
```

(Done succesfully)

3- i entered to sublimetext3 txt editor and tried to include

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

4- i got the following error

```
fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
2 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

OS:windows-10-pro .

Answer (score 2):

Did you added include path for gtk header files when compile?

Run `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags` to see which folder gtk header files in, and add those flags when compile your program.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not add screenshots of plain text. Instead just copy&paste the text and add it directly to the body of your answer. Preferably formatted as code.

Comment: i after exucting  your command i get the following error : Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'gtk+-3.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found

Comment: @Gerhardh sorry about that, but I think the direct image will make sense. 
@soldiercaptain what is the result after you run `pgk-config --list-all | grep gtk` command?

Comment: Hmm.., I think you're right, thanks for reminding, I'll update the answer.
Btw, my commands and error message are easy to retype. :v